# mongo db Error : has stopped working

Tags: mongodb

I download mongodb(windows 64-bit 2008 R2+ legacy)Binary from https://www.mongodb.org/downloads and exteract it to wamp/bin/mongodb and create data , data/db , conf , conf/mongodb.cong , logs , logs/mongodb.log file and folder and next open cmd and Enter command like this code:

```
mongod.exe --install --config c:\wamp\bin\mongodb\mongodb-win32...2.x.x\conf\mongodb.conf --logpath c:\wamp\bin\mongodb\mongodb-win32...2.x.x\logs\mongodb.log
```

and windows give me this error

[image]

Comment: This belongs to http://dbs.stackexchange.com Voted to migrate. As a side node: Running MongoDB on Win is... ...(far) less than optimal for production. For development, I'd suggest looking into the excellent [mtools by MongoDB's Thomas Rueckstiess](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools) to set up the test environment. Or use a ready made VM/docker container.